# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, amazon-s3

> I'm running Html file from S3 bucket in that HTML file there is AJAX call  when I run/open the HTML file I am getting below error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)**

My code from s3 bucket JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.get("https://52.221.186.121/email_view/6/", function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        email_otp = JSON.stringify(data);
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var input_value = $('#entered_otp').val();
            alert(input_value);
            alert(email_otp);
            if (email_otp == input_value) {
                alert('matches');
                $('.modal').removeClass('show');

            }
            else {
                alert('not matching');

                window.location = "https://awslocation.com/mobile/index.html";

            }
        });
    });


});
```

> Corresponding views.py code

```
def email_view(request, id):
    course = get_object_or_404(CourseWare, pk=id)
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
    myorder = MyOrder.objects.get_or_create(buyer=user, course=course)
    if myorder:
        sms_otp = randint(10000, 100000)
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
        email = user.user.email
    body = '''Dear User, \n Please Enter the OTP to view the Course.
                                          \n \n OTP : %s \n \n Thanks,''' % (
        sms_otp)
        email = EmailMessage('Course Ware OTP', body, to=[email])
        email.send()
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(sms_otp), content_type="application/json")
```

taceback

```
27.6.180.134 - - [12/Jun/2017:17:24:40 +0000] "GET /email_view/6/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "url_from_html_page_in_s3_bucket" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
27.6.180.134 - - [12/Jun/2017:17:53:59 +0000] "GET /email_view/6/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "url_from_html_page_in_s3_bucket" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^email_view/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$', 'admin.views.course_ware.email_view',
    name='email_view'
    ),
```

Comment: do you have the traceback? it should be in the logs

Comment: here is my traceback. I edited my question.

Comment: Could you, please, add urls.py?

Comment: i added urls.py

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything when request isn't ajax call.

Try adding:

```
return HttpResponse('It failed')
```

on the very end of `email_view` function and check if it fails.